# Identify common functions that has these properties

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

So I've gotten stuck on this problem:

> For each part below, identify a common function that has these
>   properties:
>
> A) A function that is non-negative and concave up on (-infinity,
>   infinity)
>
> B) A function that is concave down and always increasing on
>   [0,infinity)
>
> C) A function that is concave up and always increasing on (-infinity,
>   infinity)
>
> D) A function that is always increasing and has an inflection point at
>   (0,0)

How can I identify some common functions for the above properties?

Comment: y=x^2  for A, C and D

Comment: your example is good for A, but it is not good for C, as it is not increasing. Try with exponential and with logarithms. Finally, what is the main example of a function with an inflection?

Comment: A cubic polynomial?

Comment: Next time do put what you've tried into your question, so that people can give more relevant guidance.

Answer (score 0):

For A) and C) take $y=e^x$.

For B) take $y=\log (x+1)$.

For D) take $y=x^3$.